# Clonezilla part-to-part doesn't show sda2 as source

Tags: ssd, clonezilla, partclone

I needed to replace my 500G HDD with 256G SSD drive.

1. I shrunk the original partitions,
2. properly aligned SDD's partitions on 1 MiB (2048 sectors)
3. and in Parted Magic successfully transfered sda1 (old HDD) EXT4 boot partition to new sdc1 (SSD drive) using Clonezilla's part-to-part (direct disc to disc) transfer.

**The problem: Clonezilla doesn't see my second partition on the old HDD - sda2**. This one is of 'extended' type and contains LVM2 PV.
[image]
I cannot continue with my data transfer. Can anyone chip in with an advice on how to remedy this and - maybe- why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Gee, so many willing experts here. Again I had to solve my own issue. Clonezilla simply cannot do this. Don't know whether in general or due to some weir constellation of stars only in this case. I had to plug source and target using SATA adapters and shamefully do the copy using windows-based software.

Message to posterity: it is quite possible Ghost included in Parted Magic (not Norton Ghost, but that would be probably possible as well) would be able to do the copy, although painfully slowly (approx. 6 hours for the 250 GB drive).